# Rendering HTMLDivElements in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my first ReactJS project, I have constructed a DIV object using functions like documents.createElement(...). In my ReactJS project, I pass this object with props down to another component (let's call it C), where I want to render said object. However, the console is telling me the following error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement])...

I know the object is structured the way I want, and the project will render placeholder text. Why doesn't React allow me to do the following in C's render() function?

```
return (
  <div key={uuidv4()}>
    {this.props.divObject}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: If you want to deal with passing vdom to component, you might want to consider using `props.children` which is designed to do that. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React code works on the `virtual DOM`, which is essentially a tree of Javascript objects.  You're trying to create a real DOM element and insert in in to the render function.  While it appears that you are using HTML elements when you write `<div>` tags in Javascript, this is not the case.  These `<div>` tags in javascript translate in to `React.createElement` function calls, not actual divs.  The actual creation of the html elements is abstracted away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create an actual DOM element using `document.createElement`. React is only dealing with virtual DOM element, that you can create using `React.createElement`.

That said, I think there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do using the `children` property.

Your component's `render` will look like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

And in the parent's component

```
return (
<C>
  <div>I am going to be inserted in `C`'s children props</div>
</C>
)
```

Also, notice that you don't need the `key=uuidv4()` as this will change at each render thus killing the advantages of the `key` attribute (it is a way for React to create a one to one mapping between the real DOM and the virtual DOM and optimize the changes it does)